Home assistant AMG8839 and display ST7789 280x240
Hello I have the next code:
substitutions:
  name: test
  

esphome:
  name: ${name}
  name_add_mac_suffix: false
  project:
    name: esphome.web
    version: '1.0'
  includes:
    - amg8833.h
    - amg8833_camera.h
    - amg8833_person_detected.h
  libraries:
    - "Wire"
    - "SparkFun GridEYE AMG88 Library"

esp32:
  board: esp32dev
  framework:
    type: arduino


esp32_ble:
  io_capability: none
  enable_on_boot: false

# Enable logging
logger:

# Enable Home Assistant API
api:

# Allow Over-The-Air updates
ota:

# Allow provisioning Wi-Fi via serial
improv_serial:

wifi:
  # Set up a wifi access point
  ssid: "my_ssid"
  password: "my_password"

# In combination with the `ap` this allows the user
# to provision wifi credentials to the device via WiFi AP.
captive_portal:

dashboard_import:
  package_import_url: github://esphome/example-configs/esphome-web/esp32.yaml@main
  import_full_config: true

# Sets up Bluetooth LE (Only on ESP32) to allow the user
# to provision wifi credentials to the device.
esp32_improv:
  authorizer: none

# To have a "next url" for improv serial
web_server:
  port: 80
  version: 2

i2c:
  sda: GPIO21
  scl: GPIO22
  scan: True
 
text_sensor:
  - platform: custom
    lambda: |-
      auto amg8833 = new AMG8833CameraComponent();
      App.register_component(amg8833);
      return {amg8833};


    text_sensors:
      - name: "Sensor Pixels"


binary_sensor:
  - platform: custom
    lambda: |-
      auto amg8833 = new AMG8833PersonDetectedComponent();
      App.register_component(amg8833);
      return {amg8833};
    binary_sensors:
      name: "Person Detected"
      device_class: occupancy


sensor:
  - platform: custom
    lambda: |-
      auto amg8833 = new AMG8833Component();
      App.register_component(amg8833);
      return {amg8833->sensor_temperature, amg8833->max_temperature, amg8833->min_temperature, amg8833->avg_temperature, amg8833->min_index, amg8833->max_index};


    sensors:
      - name: "Thermal Sensor Temperature"
        unit_of_measurement: °C
        device_class: temperature
        accuracy_decimals: 2


      - name: "Thermal Sensor Max"
        unit_of_measurement: °C
        device_class: temperature
        accuracy_decimals: 2


      - name: "Thermal Sensor Min"
        unit_of_measurement: °C
        device_class: temperature
        accuracy_decimals: 2


      - name: "Thermal Sensor Avg"
        unit_of_measurement: °C
        device_class: temperature
        accuracy_decimals: 2


      - name: "Thermal Sensor Min Index"
        accuracy_decimals: 0


      - name: "Thermal Sensor Max Index"
        accuracy_decimals: 0
      
    

spi:
  id: myspi
  clk_pin: GPIO18 #SCL
  mosi_pin: GPIO19 #SDA


font:
  - file: "gfonts://Roboto"
    id: roboto
    size: 20


display:
  - platform: st7789v
    spi_id: myspi
    model: ADAFRUIT_RR_280X240
    backlight_pin: GPIO4
    cs_pin: GPIO14
    dc_pin: GPIO32
    reset_pin: GPIO15
    eightbitcolor: True
    update_interval: 5s
    lambda: |-

My problem its that i dont know how to display my thermal cam in my display via home assistant esphome. Here u have the image that its working so i dont know how to print this in my display.
If anyone knows how to do it i will be grateful.
Thanks.
enter image description here
I tried to put the http in the lambda but i think i put it wrongly
